# How to extract information from html elements using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, data-extraction

I would like to have a python script that will extract the information from the html link elements href.
Here is the example html code:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('4c33088a-08e8-4422-9f3d-ed65411889ef')/Products('Quicklook')/$value"/>
<id>4c33088a-08e8-4422-9f3d-ed65411889ef</id>
```

The https link in the href attribute is a download link and I would like to have python script that will automate the download. I tried data extraction with selenium and request libraries but I could not make any progress.
Any chance that I can find a solution?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Where is this HTML snippet from? As there is a `$value` parameter and other `Product()` functions in the URL, I think it is from an unrendered HTML template?

Comment: Its from a website that contains the sentinel-images informations. It requires username/password  to enter so I can not publish the html code. I just need a python code to have the file that is in the <link href>

Answer (score 0):

This Article might help
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/downloading-files-from-web-using-python
it's a very simple solution using the requests package to get the content of the website you want to then download it. Here's a little example from the tutorial:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('facebook.ico', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, i do not want to download the website url, i want to download a link which is in a <link href="here">.

Comment: Ooooh sorry for the misunderstanding. Will try to find a solution for this